# Kafka Stream - TimeWindows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question about TimeWindows with Kafka Streams, some concepts are really confusing me.

We have a Topic that get 10 million events per day and we have log retention of 6 days, so in total topic contains 60 million events.

Actually only current days events are interesting for us, the rest we keep for 5 days only for auditing reasons.

Now I created a KTable from it I am making a load all operation and iterate over the events. As I mentioned before actually we are only interested events of current day and not 60 millions events, so I windowed that data in KTable definition.

```
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)).until(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
```

now when I load the all events with the following statement everything runs fine.

```
store().fetchAll(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), System.currentTimeMillis())
```

The problem with this while early in the day, this will load lets 1 million events but later 10 millions, so I have to iterate over 10 million events, while we are working in batch mode, I thought I can further optimise this and only load events for last hour so for the same KTable configuration, I tried to use following statement.

```
store().fetchAll(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), System.currentTimeMillis())
```

but for my surprise this didn't returned any data back.

Can somebody explain why this is not returning any results, I guess I am misinterpreting something in TimeWindow concept.

Then I made some further tests and changed my KTable configuration to following.

```
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1)).until(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)))
```

now this query functions as I would like

```
store().fetchAll(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), System.currentTimeMillis())
```

but I am not sure I am in the correct path...

If I will use the following statement for latest KTable configuration would this deliver me 10 million events from current day?

```
store().fetchAll(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1), System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use interactive queries on a windowed store, the time range is applied to the window start timestamp. Thus, if you have a 1-day window, and query for data with window start timestamp from `[now - 1 hour, now)`, you won't find any matching windows, because no window start in this time range.

Comment: Ok, first thx for answer... will the second constellation work? If I have 1 hour window with window retention 1 day, if I query with [now - 1 day, now] will deliver everything from current day or still only the last hour?

Comment: I will return all data from the whole day. You can query everything within the retention time span.